# createNodeIterator fails in IE9 when acceptNode is specified

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, dom, iterator, treenode

### Target

I'd like to loop through DOM text nodes, sorted by their order inside the DOM. Furthermore I'd like to filter nodes by custom logic (e.g. check if a node is inside a specific element). Additionally all this should be done in the best possible performance and working in IE9+.

### Method

All of the above requirements are met with either

- [document.createTreeWalker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker) or
- [document.createNodeIterator()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator)

I don't fully understand why these similiar functions aren't merged together. But, as `createTreeWalker()` has more API methods I've started using it.

Then I found out that according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTreeWalker), the `acceptNode` filter function isn't supported in IE9. Therefore I switched over to `createNodeIterator`, which hasn't this restriction according to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator).

This is the code I'm using to loop through the elements:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <div class="context">
      Root first
        <div>
          Child
        </div>
      Root second
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var treeWalker = document.createNodeIterator(
            document.querySelector(".context"),
            NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
            {
                acceptNode: function(){
                    return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
                }
          },
          false
        );

        var nodeList = [];
        var currentNode;
        while (currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()){
            nodeList.push(currentNode);
        }

        console.log(nodeList);

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While the loop actually does (almost) nothing in this case, in my real application it does. So please see this just as an example.

### Issue

The problem is that the above will not work in IE9. It seems like the `acceptNode` filter callback property of `createNodeIterator` isn't supported in IE9 too. It must be `null` to work. However, as the documentation says it's supported, I expect it to work.

What I expect:

[image: Expect]

The actual message:

[image: Actual]

### Question

What's the problem here and how to fix it? Note that I definitely need to have the loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I actually have the exact same error in IE11.

If you look at the W3C documentation for [Document Object Model Level 2 Traversal and Range](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/Overview.html) and more specifically the Appendix C regarding [ECMAScript Language Binding](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Traversal-Range/ecma-script-binding.html), the NodeFilter object is defined as the following:

> This is an ECMAScript function reference. This method returns a Number. The parameter is a Node object.

So if you updates your script to pass a function instead of an object with a key `acceptNode`, you'll get the expected result.

```
var treeWalker = document.createNodeIterator(
    document.querySelector(".context"),
    NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
    function(){
        return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
    },
    false
);
```

The result in Firefox will be:

[image: Firefox result]

In Chrome you'll get:

[image: Chrome result]

And in IE, you'll have:

[image: IE result]

I didn't modify your loop or anything else to get these results so I posted only the relevant part.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I'll test this tomorrow in all browsers to make sure the function instead of the object works everywhere. However, the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeFilter) explicitely uses an object containing a property `acceptNode`. And even on the [`createNodeIterator documentation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator) they explicitely say: `An object implementing the NodeFilter interface; its acceptNode() method will be called for each node`. Do you think the documentation is wrong?

Comment: The MDN documentation is not wrong, it works on MDN compliant browsers. They implemented and documented the raw W3C spec which state that a `NodeFilter contains 1 acceptNode method`. They're not documenting the way described in the Appendix C relative to the ECMAScript Binding even if they're supporting it and it's the only way IE is supporting it. I even found [a ticket](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=113008) in their bug tracker stating that the recommendation for ECMAScript binding was not implemented at first and they fixed it later according to the W3C specs.

Comment: So summarized: IE only accepts a function rather than an object with a key `acceptNode` (btw: do you have a reference for this?). Firefox supports both, but the documentation only describes the object variant. Is this correct?

Comment: That's totally correct. Regarding IE, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff974820(v=vs.85).aspx) provides the documentation for the filter. It's indeed described as a `callback function that provides customized filtering` and not an object. The example they provide also reflect that.

Comment: I've just tested this in Firefox, Chrome and IE9-11 and it works in all. I'm going to accept your answer as it provided a working solution and background information. The incomplete and different documentations are really annoying... Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I think the part where you actually have your loop is where things are messed up. I do understand what you are trying to do, but I figured a way that I believe you can use to still achieve the same results:

```
 try{ 
       var treeWalker = document.createNodeIterator(
         document.querySelector(".context"),
         NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
         { acceptNode: function(node)
              { return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT; }
         },
      false
      );
    //This will help you avoid the loop you currently have on your code, but you wold still need one if you want to have a wrapper task that you want to perform on your treelist items

     var nodeList = treeWalker.root.childNodes;

     console.log(nodeList [0]);
 }catch(e){
   console.log(e);
 }
```

//Version 2

```
var nodeIterator = document.createNodeIterator(
    document.body,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT,
    function(node) {
        return node.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'p' ? NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT : NodeFilter.FILTER_REJECT;
    },
    false
);
var pars = [];
//what you were missing for it to work on IE
    var currentNode = "<p></p>";


while (currentNode = nodeIterator.nextNode()) {
  console.dir(currentNode); // or console wherever you want
  pars.push(currentNode);
}
```

Comment: You do not really need the try block, I was using that to debug the code, thought i'd get a much more explicit error message.

Comment: While the result may be the same, in my real application I really need a loop so just removing it isn't a solution for me.

Comment: You can keep your loop, it's clearly breaking on IE 9. I suggested on my comment that you could still write one.

Comment: Then please suggest a working solution for IE9 using a loop

Comment: You have  var nodeList = [];
        var currentNode;
        while (currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()){
            nodeList.push(currentNode);
        }
in your code:
1) I am not sure why you have currentNode compared to treeWalker.nextNode, currentNode never seems to be updated anywhere else in your code, so what are you comparing ? a null and and object, I guess that is one of the reasons there is a break on IE, remember IE is not vert graceful like the other browsers. i created an object that come prepopulated with what you need var nodeList = treeWalker.root.childNodes; loop it.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot write a loop for you, you need to create one yourself as you are the one with the idea of what you need to achieve.


for(var item in nodeList){
  yourObject.push(nodeList[item]);
}

That's one way you can still write your loop, but still i do not understand the need for your loop, you probably need to explain to us what it's for as i provided a solution already for you which you find not helpful for your needs. Thanks.

Comment: @HIawu We've misunderstood us. The loop `while (currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode()){` should work, as the API is supported according to the documentation. So, I don't understand why I should use your workaround and that is my question: What is going on here? Why is it breaking? I see myself that the reason is the loop, but I don't see why. And your answer doesn't answer this.

Comment: Which part of the documentation talks about the support for the loop that you have so we can see if there is anything you missed ?

Comment: See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createNodeIterator) and [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeIterator/nextNode) page, scroll down to "Browser Compatibility". It says "IE9+"

Comment: `I am not sure why you have currentNode compared to treeWalker.nextNode, currentNode never seems to be updated anywhere else in your code, so what are you comparing ?`. The `=` is an assignment, not a check! However, we should stop commenting here, as I don't think you're getting the point. Sorry.